# Install kubuntu 20.04 no grub and 11gb

Tags: grub2, kubuntu

I have kdeneon as my main driver and main partition.

I want my second partition to have a minimal kubuntu 20.04 install and only 11 gb partition.  (It is for ardour and only that).  After I change things for ardour my system gets too high powered so it is best to have a separate system.

I tried to install kde neon as the small partition which the installer let me do, but I had a grub nightmare.  I just could not get grub back to the first install over a few days and lots of help..
I lost both partitions while trying to fix it.

It seems that kubuntu wants 20gb or no install is allowed.

It seems that this trick to not install grub is for two physical hard drives.

Is there a way to fix this for one drive and one grub.?

Comment: The recommended minimum disk size for Ubuntu Desktop has been 25GB for Ubuntu releases since 17.10 (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements) and 11gb is a fair bit below recommended minimum...

Comment: minimum install installs completely far below 10gb.. i know this from my kdeneon install and the stated nightmare.

Comment: KDE Neon isn't Ubuntu, nor *flavor* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) so I don't see how it relates here.

Comment: i'm looking to install kubuntu NOT kde neon.  The fact that I know it won't install already shows I have tried.  it is Ubuntu.  I said my daily driver is kdeNeon.. I want to install Kubuntu on 10 gb partition.  The reason for the split is I think the UEFI was confused with two identical partitions.  So I was hoping to install kubuntu.  I'll install anything actually.  I just want ardour to run and have a low latency kernel.  It is a once a month boot for me.  It seems as though I might be able to run the installer from the command line with -b.  That will fix 1 of 2  problems

Comment: I didn't vote to close as I realize you're asking about Kubuntu, however your 11gb is well below what is the recommended minimum since 17.10, and expecting Kubuntu to install when you've met the minimum requirements for a completely different OS (KDE Neon) is I still believe is a stupid user-error. KDE Neon is not Ubuntu, nor Kubuntu; thus its minimums are unrelated, you should meet the Kubuntu minimums for a Kubuntu install.

Comment: I'm looking into lubuntu.. anything buntu.  I don't see if there is a spec for it.  I have  to pay for downloads, so I want to know before.  I have the kubuntu and ubuntu iso now. I wonder if there is a way to launch the installer without the restrictions.  Kubuntu installer (i know i tried) offere a minimal installation option.

Comment: Use `zsync` to download the differences; from a prior ISO.   Even if you start with a 19.10 ISO as example and want to download a 20.10 ISO, you may only need to download 40-60% of the total size (ie. differences... pick the right ISO and you may need to download 30%... comparison/calculation costs cpu.cycles and not bandwidth.. so use zsync or equiv).  https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/index.html is Lubuntu manual , but Lubuntu has avoided providing minimums since 19.04 cycle.   (*Lubuntu uses `calamares` or same installer as neon, but I can't recall what requirements are set to*)

Comment: It seems that the calamares installer does not have an option to exclude the boot stuff.  Actually it is the writing to wifi that causes the problems.  There is an issue in GitHub.

Comment: I'll probably install ubuntu running the ubiquity installer "ubiquity -b" and then shrink the partition.  After shrinking it.. i should be able to do a grub update on the other partition and it should find it.  I'm taking  a break.. I'll hopefully update the answer next week

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem.

Temporarily give the partition 20gb using gparted or kde partition manager.
gparted is better for me.

start the usb disk and open a terminal

```
CTRL + ALT  + T
```

start the installer manually with -b parameter to exclude the grub install

```
ubiquity -b
```

Install into your 20gb drive using the normal or manual option.
**You should only be doing this with the minimal installation option and intentions to keep a lean system.**

Before booting your new system (which you cannot do anyway), load up your main Linux system and restore your drive to 12gb using gparted.  You will get warnings that your system might not boot, but since it is not added to the grub startup menu yet, it does not matter.  It is also a secondary system you have not used yet anyway.  Go ahead.

While in your main system type the following in terminal.

```
sudo udpate-grub
```

You can now restart and your new partition will be seen in the grub startup menu.  Boot your new installation and do whatever you want accordingly.

Comment: Well done.   fyi:  typo: `update-grub` and not udpate..